# Is there a way to find the time a YouTube livestream started?

Tags: youtube, live

I’m wondering if anyone knows a way to find the exact time that a YouTube livestream started. I’ve tried googling and haven’t been able to find anything useful. The livestream is not mine.

Thanks!!

Comment: I think the best place to ask this question to get the best answers is https://superuser.com/ (its not something professional webmasters worry about) but since you already asked .... if the stream is running you can slide the bar on the bottom to the left or hover over it and it will give the number of minutes as a negative value say -15:30 ... the stream started -15:30 ago.

Comment: Note: After the author asked this on Super User, it looks like [that question was then migrated here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/169051/is-there-any-way-to-see-when-a-youtube-livestream-started).